# Catching signals: Use a member function as signal handler

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have an object which does some work in an endless loop. The `main()` instantiates the object and calls the `run()` method. Since I don't want to use threads, I need a solution to make my object stop running. Below you see what I've come up with.

```
struct Foo
{
    void run()
    {
        running = 1;
        while (running) 
            do_something_useful();

        std::cout << "Execution stopped." << std::endl;
    }

    bool running;

    void catch_signal(int signal)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught signal " << signal << std::endl;
        if( signal == SIGTERM ) 
            running = false;
    }

};
```

As you see, I need to send a signal asynchronously. Therefore, I use a signal handler and `sigaction`. Below the `main` I can imagine to use.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo foo;
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;

    boost::function< void (int) > f;
    f = std::bind1st(
      std::mem_fun(&Foo::catch_signal), &foo);
    f(5);  // this call works

    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = f;           // compiler complains, "cannot assign ..."
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
    s.run();

}
```

What I would expect now: The program runs until I send `SIGTERM` which is caught and will cause my object to stop iteration and return to main.

I have two questions now:

(a) In the code you see a line marked with "Compiler complains", the message is like

```
boost::function<void(int)> cannot be converted to __sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}
```

What do I need to change to make this work? I think `f` is like `void f(int)`, like the functions the signal handler gets in some examples.

(b) For those of you who wonder "what is that guy doing?": Do you have any advice how to solve this kind of thing better?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not wish to use threads? Though I have not used boost at all, my assumption it's expecting a callback function to be provided.

Comment: Like starting ``Foo::run()`` in a thread, catching the signal in ``main`` and let the main call sth. like ``thread.terminate()``? Yes, would be a possibility, but I thought it would be too much for this.

Comment: That's one way for certain. The other that (in my sedated miasma of thinking) is that you could have a struct with whatever information in it you need, register it as a thread, so you run the loop with you normal main functions in it, and the signal handler running on it's own thread, then you just grab the value byref to see if an event happened, and if so what event and the appropriate response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - What do I need to change to make this work? I think f is like void f(int), like the functions the signal handler gets in some examples.

The compiler complains about the type, therefore you need to pass a function pointer, not an object of type `boost::function<void(int)>`. Creating a global variable of this type, and adding a function which calls this object would work :

```
boost::function<void(int)> myCb;
void CallCb( int value )
{
  myCb(value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo foo;
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;

    myCb = std::bind1st(
      std::mem_fun(&Foo::catch_signal), &foo);
    f(5);  // this call works

    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = CallCb;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
    s.run();

}
```

> - Do you have any advice how to solve this kind of thing better?

Not really. The idea is ok. I would just just c++11 lambda instead

Answer (score 3):

There is very little that you can do portably in a signal handler. Basically, you can store a value in an object whose type is `sig_atomic_t`. Inserting into `cout`, for example, doesn't have to work. If you have C++11 you can do a bit more, using atomic types or explicit fences, but any other calls into the standard library aren't required to do anything sensible.

So, with all that said, what you can do is write a function (either a free function or a static member function (but there is a subtle issue here with C++ linkage: formally a static member function won't work, but in practice it always does)) that calls the member function, which in turn sets `running` to `false` (assuming you've changed the type of `running` to `sig_atomic_t`).